# need javascript function allow comma and space

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation

I use the following function for integer validation on **keydown event**.now i need to allow **comma and space bar** within this .how to do this?

```
function intValidate(event) {
    if ( event.keyCode == 46 || event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 9 || event.keyCode == 27 || event.keyCode == 13 ||(event.keyCode == 65 && event.ctrlKey === true) ||(event.keyCode >= 35 && event.keyCode <= 39))
        {
            return;
        }
    else 
    {
        if (event.shiftKey || (event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57) && (event.keyCode < 96 || event.keyCode > 105 )&&event.keyCode < 188)
        {
            event.preventDefault(); 
        }   
    }
  }
```

Comment: Search for the relative keyCode and use them in your conditions.

Answer (score 3):

Check for the key codes 188 and 32, respectively. Whereas 188 is "comma", you may also want to check for 110 – "decimal point", for the character on your numpad (depending on keyboard layout, of course).

Comment: sorry, I got the comma and period key codes mixed up first. see my update

Answer (score 1):

Add the Keycodes for the new Chars you need to allow in your If statement. tr this [Keycodes List](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes)

Answer (score 0):

`32` will be for Space.

`188` will be for Comma(,).

So Add it in your `if` condition:

```
event.keyCode == 32 || event.keyCode == 188
```

See the whole list: [KeyCode List](http://www.webonweboff.com/tips/js/event_key_codes.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can call this function:

```
var isValid = function(key) {

    var allowedCharacters = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9',' ', ',']
    if (allowedCharacters.contains(key)) return true;
    return false;

};
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Js9wQ/

Comment: How would you implement that in a keydown listener?

Comment: var key = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);